# Assign java method reference to an interface

Tags: java, lambda, interface

I bump into some java code and could not understand why it compiles.

The code pass a method reference to a method while the method accepts an interface.

Based on my knowledge of java, this is not allowed but to my surprise, the compiler accepts it.

But if I alter part of the method signature, compile fails.

Please refer to the code before

Could anybody give an explanation why compiler accepts a.injector(TextMap::put)  and rejects a.injector(TextMap::put2) and a.injector(TextMap::put3).

==============

```
package testJava;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

final Map<Object, InjectorInterface<TextMap>> formatToInjector = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public interface TextMap {
    void put(String key, String value);

    void put2(String key, Integer value);

    void put3(Integer key, String value);
}

interface InjectorInterface<C> {
    InjectorInterface<C> inject(Object traceContext, C carrier);
}

public interface Propagation<K> {

    interface Setter<C, K> {
        void put(C carrier, K key, String value);
    }

    <C> InjectorInterface<C> injector(Setter<C, K> setter);
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public Test(final String condition) {
    final Propagation<String> a = null;
    // Let us forget the fact that a is null.
    this.formatToInjector.put(new Object(), a.injector(TextMap::put)); // compile pass.
    //      this.formatToInjector.put(new Object(), a.injector(TextMap::put2));// compile fail.
    //      this.formatToInjector.put(new Object(), a.injector(TextMap::put3));// compile fail.
}
}
```

Comment: Based on your knowledge of Java, what method signature *should* accept a method reference?

Answer (score 1):

Here - the signature of `inject()` is:

```
void put(C carrier, K key, String value);
```

It expects a C, a K and a **String**. And because of the declaration `Propagation<String> a` (which uses **String**, too), the type K **key** must be **String** too.

Now lets have a look at the method you intend to use:

```
void put(String key, String value);
```

uses a **String** key and value.

`put2()` and `put3()` do not! These methods have different types for key resp. value.

Thus `put()` is the only method here which has a matching signature!

Comment: I understand your point but could please explain why compiler rejects a.injector(TextMap::put2) and a.injector(TextMap::put3).

Comment: Would you please explain in more details? I pass TextMap::put to injector method and let's assume TextMap::put gets evaluated and returns void. But injector method accepts Setter interface. Are you claiming that somehow TextMap::put reference turned into an object of Setter interface?

Comment: I am catching your point that compiler accepts that line of code because the signature matches. and there is some kind notion of currying from right most. Anyway, Thanks for your answer, it helps me understand the code.

Comment: sure. just in case you intend to wait some more time for other answers ... still dont forget to accept some answer at some point ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think I find the answer for the question. It can be explained by method reference in java. Please refer to page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html to find out the answer.